# Extracting the City and State from Geocoder in Android

Tags: android, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm attempting to extract the City and State only from the Geocoder in Android. I've gotten pretty far to where it extracts the city fine, but the state I'm having issues with its printing the zip along side it.

I'm looking for "City, State" whereas the final output now is "City, State Zip"

Any ideas?

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 10);
                     int i=1;
                     for(Address addObj:addresses)
                     {
                         // Looping once
                         if(i==1)
                         {

                             String add_line1_extract;

                             add_line1_extract=addObj.getAddressLine(1);

                             String string = add_line1_extract;
                             String[] parts = string.split(",");

                             //Setting city
                             mCity = parts[0]; 

                             //setting state
                             mState = parts[1]; 

                             // Final Output
                             String cityAndState = mCity + ", " + mState;
                             i++;

                         }
                     }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the state name by calling the [getAdminArea()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getAdminArea()) method from Address class. However, it might not work for all the countries. Also, you could call the [getLocality()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getLocality()) to retrieve the city name.

So for your code, you can do the following:

```
String cityName = addObject.getLocality();    
String stateName = addObject.getAdminArea();
String cityAndState = cityName + ", " + stateName;
```

If you want the abbreviation of a state name, you can do further split in your `String[] parts`. You can do the following:

```
String[] moreSplit = parts[1].split(" ");
String mStateAbbr = moreSplit[0];
String mCityAndStateAbbr = mCity + mStateAbbr;
```

Comment: Unfortunately getAdminArea(); is returning the full state name instead of the abbreviations only. Any thoughts on fixing that?